# select default value in dropdown

Tags: asp.net

how to select default value in dropdown
here is the dropdown

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" 
    class="vpb_dropdown" DataTextField="ApproveType" DataValueField="ApproveID"
        AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged">
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Pending"  Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Approve" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Reject" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

i want to select pending as default..

Comment: I just noticed you have `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` set... that's used in Data Binding... is there a data source you aren't showing? Why is that there?

Answer (score 10):

How about:

```
DropDownList4.SelectedValue = 3
```

Or set the `value` to 0 to make it default with no code.

Comment: in database approvetype table there is 1 as approve 2 set as reject and 3 as pending ..here i want to set default value pedning in dropdown..

Comment: @tymeJV SelectedValue should be a string... perhaps he ran into problem copying the code exactly.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to do it from the code behind, you can do it using `Selected`:

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Pending" Selected="true" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
```

MSDN: [ListItem Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Above answer is correct you can do it in the mark up as noted above by including:

```
SelectedValue= "3"

            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"      class="vpb_dropdown" DataTextField="ApproveType" SelectedValue= "3" DataValueField="ApproveID"         AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dzka5sf(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Using this approach, I get this error "Parser Error Message: The 'SelectedValue' property cannot be set declaratively."

Answer (score 3):

Put this in your page_load event

```
DropDownList4.SelectedIndex = 0 ;
```

This will set your drop down to the first item on the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value representing for pending first, let say PedingValue. Then:

```
DropDownList4.SelectedValue = PendingValue;
```

in the Page_load event.